# MATLAB : How to use fsolve with multiple inputs, each dependent on multiple parameters?

Tags: matlab, anonymous-function, numerical-methods

I am trying to solve the following system of 4 equations with 4 unknowns, and I do not like the numerical results I get from vpasolve , so I read a part of the vast documentation for fsolve .

I have the following system of 4 equations, in which the terms: `T1,T2,T3,E1,E2,E3,S1,S2,S3,S4 are known` and the terms `a,b,g,D are unknowns`.

For an estimate:

```
T1, T2 and T3 are 303, 323, 343

E1, E2 and E3 are 5e+06, 10e+06, 20e+06

S1, S2, S3 and S4 are 1.52e-06 ; 3.36e-06 ; 6.62e-07 ; 1.38e-06

Estimate values for the unknowns (a;b;g;D) should be around (+-1e-7;+-1e-5;+-0.1;10), but not necessarily.
```

The system is:

```
(a*T1+b)*E1 = asinh( S1/(D*(E1)^g) )
(a*T2+b)*E3 = asinh( S2/(D*(E3)^g) )
(a*T3+b)*E2 = asinh( S3/(D*(E2)^g) )
(a*T3+b)*E3 = asinh( S4/(D*(E3)^g) )
```

In order to make the system "work" with fsolve I did the following:

```
F1 = @(a,b,g,D) ( asinh( 1.52e-06/(D*(5*1e06)^g) )-(a*303+b)*(5*1e06) )
F2 = @(a,b,g,D) ( asinh( 3.36e-06/(D*(20*1e06)^g) )-(a*323+b)*(20*1e06) )
F3 = @(a,b,g,D) ( asinh( 6.62e-07/(D*(10*1e06)^g) )-(a*343+b)*(10*1e06) )
F4 = @(a,b,g,D) ( asinh( 1.38e-06/(D*(20*1e06)^g) )-(a*343+b)*(20*1e06) )
```

I then wrote

```
r = @(a,b,g,D) [ F1(a,b,g,D) ; F2(a,b,g,D) ; F3(a,b,g,D) ; F4(a,b,g,D) ]
```

And with that, I wrote

```
[x, fval, exitflag] = fsolve(r, [1e-7,1e-5,0.1,10])
```

I get the following error:

> Error using
>   @(a,b,g,D)[F1(a,b,g,D);F2(a,b,g,D);F3(a,b,g,D);F4(a,b,g,D)] Not enough
>   input arguments.
>
> Error in fsolve (line 219)
>               fuser = feval(funfcn{3},x,varargin{:});
>
> Caused by:
>       Failure in initial user-supplied objective function evaluation. FSOLVE cannot continue.

I then tried various other ways of declaring the functions, but all of them eventually resulted in the same error - or other errors, but probably due to bad formatting.

I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make the distinction between:

- a vector containing 4 elements (= what  `fsolve` expects)
- 4 arguments containing 1 element (=what you provide)

The easiest solution is to expand the vector as follows:

```
[x, fval, exitflag] = fsolve(@(x) r(x(1), x(2), x(3), x(4)), [1e-7,1e-5,0.1,10])
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  This now makes a lot of sense.